Enable ARP Announcement on Linux built with yocto
When connecting my Linux computer (Ubuntu 22.04, Kernel 5.15) to the network I see an ARP Announcement according to the Wireshark print screen below.
For an embedded device I build my Linux using yocto (dunfell) with Kernel 5.10. When I connecting this device to the network I doesn't see the ARP Announcement.
Where do I have to enable this ARP Announcement in the yocto recipe, are additional packages required for this? Or is it a Linux kernel configuration?
The embedded device has support for ARP it self and returns correctly to requests, it just doesn't send the optional Announcement after the interface setup.


[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Ok thanks for the hint. I asked the question now here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/776640/enable-arp-announcement-on-linux-built-with-yocto
